# Sobre Activities em Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Boa noite.
A minha duvida é simples. 
Meu app tem um sistema no qual eu abro 5 activities para cadastro (primeiro a activity 1, depois a 2 e assim sucessivamente. imagine que seja algo parecido com uma instalação do windows aonde tem varias janelas com "next")
Da quinta activity ela volta para a primeira, e quando o usuario precisar de um novo cadastro, o processo acontece novamente.
Este é o codigo que eu uso para passar entre as activities:

```
Intent novaActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), proximaActivity);
                novaActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("activities", activitiesSelecionadas);
                startActivity(novaActivity);
                finish();
```

Existe alguma possíbilidade de o aplicativo ficar muito pesado após varios cadastros?

Comment: Se da quinta activity o usuário voltar para a primeira depois de finalizar o cadastro o melhor é limpar o *Back Stack* e o problema deixa de existir.

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre. Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vejo a arquitetura ideal para este processo (assumindo que faz tudo parte do cadastro) é ter apenas uma Activity e 5 fragmentos. Desta maneira consegues gerir os layouts, a escalabilidade e a informação(que pode ficar toda na activity) melhor.